# How many cakes can be baked with the given ingredients (java)

Tags: java

> Write a programme that calculates how many cakes can be baked with a given amount of ingredients. For the sake of simplicity, we will use the following basic recipe:
>
> Required ingredient quantities per cake:
>
> Flour (in g): 200
> Sugar (in g): 100
> Eggs (pieces): 2
> The user is asked to enter the available quantity of the respective ingredients (in whole numbers). The system should then display how many cakes can be baked with this quantity. In addition, the remaining amount per ingredient should be displayed.
>
> Example:
>
> ? Mehl: 1000
> ? Zucker: 400
> ? Eier: 7
> Anzahl der Kuchen: 3
> Rest: 400g Mehl, 100g Zucker, 1 Ei(er)

I have now written the following programme:

flour=Mehl; sugar=Zucker; eggs=Eier

```
package einfprog;

public class Bsp02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO: Implement.
        SavitchIn in = new SavitchIn();
        
        // Zutatenmengen pro Kuchen
        int mehlProKuchen = 200;
        int zuckerProKuchen = 100;
        int eierProKuchen = 2;

        int verfuegbaresMehl = in.readInt();
        int verfuegbarerZucker = in.readInt();
        int verfuegbareEier = in.readInt();

        // Anzahl der Kuchen
        int anzahlKuchen = Math.min(
            verfuegbaresMehl / mehlProKuchen,
            Math.min(verfuegbarerZucker / zuckerProKuchen, verfuegbareEier / eierProKuchen)
        );

        // Rest
        int restMehl = verfuegbaresMehl - anzahlKuchen * mehlProKuchen;
        int restZucker = verfuegbarerZucker - anzahlKuchen * zuckerProKuchen;
        int restEier = verfuegbareEier - anzahlKuchen * eierProKuchen;

        System.out.println("Anzahl der Kuchen: " + anzahlKuchen);
        System.out.println("Rest: " + restMehl + "g Mehl, " + restZucker + "g Zucker, " + restEier + " Ei(er)");
    }
}
```

However, I am doing something wrong with the output and get the following error message:

```
Part 1 -- 0/1 tests passed:
    ❌ main(): Failed: Output does not match the expected format for part 1:
      Input: flour=0, sugar=0, eggs=0
      Your output:
Anzahl der Kuchen: 0
Rest: 0g Mehl, 0g Zucker, 0 Ei(er)
```

Unfortunately, I can't work out what I'm doing wrong (or rather, I don't understand where the English terms flour, sugar and eggs in the Input come from).
If someone could give me a tip, I would be very grateful.

Comment: It seems like that the method that is testing your code is expecting a certain format in your output. You should share the test method too.

Comment: Your ouput format is wrong. The program is expecting a certain format and type it seems. You are passing in strings "0g Mehl, 0g Zucker, 0 Ei(er)" and it's expecting 0. Either grams are unessary or you are doing something wrong but without the testing code there is nothing we can help you with.

Comment: @ADSquared I have no access to the testing code - I don't know it. Only the information in my post is available to me. The output should show how many cakes can be baked with the quantity available to the user. In addition, the remaining amount per ingredient should be displayed (as in the example in the post).

Comment: The best solution for this is using matrices and linear algebra.

Comment: For me it seems, that the english output is coming from the test code. How do you execute the test? Without knowing anything from the test code its impossible to say whats happening here.

Comment: @Semaphor: The test will be executed by the online program in which I have to program this (I am working on the introduction to java) - with the given information it should be possible to write a program as simple as mine, which fulfils the test. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and the test only gives me information about the error message.  (In my opinion, the output in my programme is the same as in the given example)

Comment: But, I agree with the first two comments. The automated judge is expecting your output in a certain format, and your output format doesn't comply. It looks like the test case actually used 3 zeroes for input. Do you have documentation on the expected output?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer The output should be how many cakes you can bake and how much flour, sugar and eggs are left over (I think based on the given example and the task!!).

This is the second programme I've written and the test drove me crazy with the first one too, because you don't really know what you're doing wrong when no more syntax errors occur.

Comment: the problem description (at least as posted here) is also very confusing - starting in English, switching to German. The posted code apparently is doing exactly as required by the **posted**, but edited, description... it would be *wise* to have the original text posted, specially regarding the output format (including line breaks and indentation)

Comment: Also not sure if it is expected to output a prompt for each input value... as shown in the Example, but missing in code

Comment: @user85421 This is the original problem description. To output a prompt for each unput value I have already tried - it does not change the error message!

Comment: But, *how* is the output to be presented? i.e.,  *in what format* ? The automated judge might what the output to be like this:  "0 0 0 0". Or like this: "Cakes: 0. Leftovers: Flour: 0. Sugar: 0. Eggs: 0" Or like this: "0 Cakes, with 0 Flour, 0 Sugar, 0 Eggs leftover." To solve this, you have to know the requirements of the automated judge.  An automated judge can be thrown off by something small, like using a `,` instead of a `.`.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer: "(Anzahl der Kuchen =) Amount of Cakes:" and "Rest: ...g flour, ...g sugar, ...eggs" - depending on user input (I interpret from the example)

Comment: I see at least one edit changing posted text - the numbers of your result are correct (I mean with ZERO input, output must be all ZERO) , so the problem must be formatting - probably including language! In other words, I suspect the output must be the exact same text as expected by the program that is testing it (no intelligence involved, just a string compare - every bit counts)

Comment: What example? The example shown comes from your code, which fails to pass the automated judge. Show us output from an example that passed, possibly from another student, or a page describing the assignment. Or, check with your professor / teacher as to how the output should be formatted.

Comment: Off-Topic: Avoiding problems like this is one reason programming practice / challenge sites often require users to code a method that returns an array, list, or other data structure.

Comment: quoting the test result: "Output does not match the **expected format**" (emphasis added) - unfortunately it does not tell what output format is expected

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved my problem with the following code (by a lot of trial and error):

```
package einfprog;

public class Bsp02 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO: Implement.
    SavitchIn in = new SavitchIn();
    
    // Zutatenmengen pro Kuchen
    int mehlProKuchen = 200;
    int zuckerProKuchen = 100;
    int eierProKuchen = 2;

    System.out.print("? Mehl: ");
    int verfuegbaresMehl = in.readInt();
    System.out.print("? Zucker: ");
    int verfuegbarerZucker = in.readInt();
    System.out.print("? Eier: ");
    int verfuegbareEier = in.readInt();

    // Anzahl der Kuchen
    int anzahlKuchen = Math.min(
        verfuegbaresMehl / mehlProKuchen,
        Math.min(verfuegbarerZucker / zuckerProKuchen, verfuegbareEier / eierProKuchen)
    );

    // Rest
    int restMehl = verfuegbaresMehl - anzahlKuchen * mehlProKuchen;
    int restZucker = verfuegbarerZucker - anzahlKuchen * zuckerProKuchen;
    int restEier = verfuegbareEier - anzahlKuchen * eierProKuchen;

    System.out.println("Anzahl der Kuchen: " + anzahlKuchen);
    System.out.println("Rest: " + restMehl + "g Mehl, " + restZucker + "g Zucker, " + restEier + " Ei(er)");
}
```

}

So the error was that it is expected to output a prompt for each input value, which I solved with

```
System.out.print("? Mehl: ");
int verfuegbaresMehl = in.readInt();
System.out.print("? Zucker: ");
int verfuegbarerZucker = in.readInt();
System.out.print("? Eier: ");
int verfuegbareEier = in.readInt();
```

Thanks for the helpful comments

Comment: seems like it was the output format ... quoting from some [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77419251/how-many-cakes-can-be-baked-with-the-given-ingredients-java#comment136486995_77419251) "*it is expected to output a prompt for each input value... as shown in the Example*"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Deduct *200*, *100*, and *2*, from your input-values, until one is *lesser-than*, or *equal-to*, *0*.

Here is an example.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = in.nextInt(), b = in.nextInt(), c = in.nextInt(), x = 0;
while (a >= 200 && b >= 100 && c >= 2) {
    x++;
    a -= 200;
    b -= 100;
    c -= 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (unfortunately I'm not allowed to use scanners and I'm not really familiar with them) - does this also work with SavitchIn and boolean?
If I understand your example correctly, my programme also does this in a certain white way (in a cumbersome way - I'm trying to solve this with my existing knowledge (which is expected). If I understand the error message correctly, I haven't made a syntax error - there's just something wrong with the output??

Comment: @Euler007, I don't follow anything you're saying.  Re-code it.